# copy header and footer between word documents in c#

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I try copy headers and footer from one word document to other programmatically in c# by Open-XML-SDK.

I found this: [Copy Header and Footer to all other Documents OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560269/copy-header-and-footer-to-all-other-documents-openxml/75742895#75742895?newreg=37886e5afbce43ee99cd1a6d36ba17bd).
It works fine if is only one header/footer defined in source file and destination file has only one section. If source file has defined different header/footer on first page and destination file has more sections, it not work correctly.
I am new in word document manipulation by Open-XML-SDK.
Can anyone help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.